# How to Trigger an AJAX call in JSF from Javascript and avoid using global functions as callback handlers?

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, myfaces, ajax4jsf

I want to move the JSF AJAX triggering code written with f:ajax, f:event and the h:commandLink (with its action attribute) to Javascript by using the jsf.util.ajax. - Why ? Because to avoid globally written handler functions to handle call backs. We are migrating the JS code to AMD Require JS and JSF isn't playing very well

Previously, the code to trigger AJAX calls from the view XHTML file in JSF was written like this :

```
<h:commandLink id="elemID" tabindex="-1" rendered="#{something.isEnabled ('showSomeLink')}">
    <f:ajax render="#{someBean.getElemId('LinkID')}" onevent="renderAjax" />
    <jsft:event type="ajax"> someBean.someMethod(); </jsft:event>
</h:commandLink>
```

The above markup gets rendered in HTML as follows:

```
<a href="#" onclick="jsf.util.chain(document.getElementById('elemID'), event,'jsf.ajax.request(\'elemID\',event,{render:\'LinkID\',onevent:renderAjax,\'javax.faces.behavior.event\':\'action\'})'); return false;" id="elemID" name="elemID" tabindex="-1"></a>
```

Then, a click event was triggered on this link to execute the AJAX and the action.

---

The `jsft:event` was used which behaves similarly to its counterpart `f:event`.

I do not want to use this because it forces to define JS functions globally. In this case, renderAjax() in the onevent attribute of f:ajax

As you can see, This relies on a globally defined function called `renderAjax()` as the callback function to execute something and render on the UI side.

The trouble is we are moving into AMD and require JS and we have no scope of defining any globals in our code (we can but we do not want to). Even if we did, this ajax call gets triggered much before Require AMD loads

So I attempted to re-write this ajax call from the client side in JS, inside an AMD module, like this (from the generated HTML snippet's onclick mentioned above)

*(Point to note, I did not know how to mention the action attribute in this JS code.)*

```
jsf.util.chain(document.getElementById('elemID'), event,'jsf.ajax.request(\'elemID\',event,{render:\'LinkID\',onevent:renderAjax,\'javax.faces.behavior.event\':\'action\'})');
```

Once I wrote the above code in JS, I removed the `f:ajax` (since the `render` and the `onevent` attributes came inside the JS code itself ) and the `jsft:event` from the view, in the XHTML file. Once I removed this, it began causing a continuous reload of the page, as an infinite loop. I had to stop the server and put back the code to its old state.

Next, I thought `h:commandLink` was the issue and decided to replace `h:commandLink` with a normally rendered anchor tag via the `h:outputLink`.

Unfortunately this doesn't have an action attribute. The point is, although the element is rendered,

```
jsf.util.chain(document.getElementById('elemID'), event,'jsf.ajax.request(\'elemID\',event,{render:\'LinkID\',onevent:renderAjax,\'javax.faces.behavior.event\':\'action\'})');
```

Since my code with `h:outputLink` has no action attribute, it doesnt execute the method in the managed Bean.

Suppose I included the `h:commandLink`, without the `jsft:event` and the `f:ajax`, then it causes an infinite page reload.

I even added the `action` attribute to the `h:commandLink` after removing the `jsft:event` and `f:ajax` . I made it work with the below update.

```
<h:commandLink id="elemID" tabindex="-1" rendered="#{something.isEnabled ('showSomeLink')}" action="#{someBean.someMethod()}">
            <f:ajax />  
        </h:commandLink>
```

and then using the following in JS:

```
jsf.util.chain(document.getElementById('elemID'), event,'jsf.ajax.request(\'elemID\',event,{render:\'LinkID\',onevent:renderAjax,\'javax.faces.behavior.event\':\'action\'})');
```

So far it works. But the problem is my renderAjax is still globally defined. Now i move my JS function into a require AMD module. The function renderAjax is no longer globally available and I move the jsf ajax code also into my module and access it as:

```
jsf.util.chain(document.getElementById('elemID'), event,'jsf.ajax.request(\'elemID\',event,{render:\'LinkID\',onevent:_t.renderAjax,\'javax.faces.behavior.event\':\'action\'})');
```

Note, _t.renderAjax() is now inside a module in Require JS. The Error i get now is _t is undefined. I guess it expects to see only global functions. The fun part is it automatically creates a wrapper function around the code. Is there any way to fix this?

```
(function(event
/**/) {
jsf.ajax.request('elemID',event,{render:'LinkID',onevent:_t.renderAjax,'javax.faces.behavior.event':'action'})
```

})

If someone could help me fix this, it would be extremely helpful.

Comment: I had to read your question 3x to get some kind of understanding of what's going on here, and I'm still not sure. Is there any reason you're not using the `f:event`? Why are you passing three arguments to `jsf.util.chain`, when it accepts only 2?

Comment: @kolossus : Thanks for the reply. I have edited the post again. please let me know if you can get it now. I'm trying to do away with Global JS functions. using the h:commandLink, f:event, f:ajax causes the callback function to be available globally. We are moving to Require AMD and we do not want globally scoped functions. So we wanted to move this Ajax call trigger into Javascript from the current JSF view XHTML using f:event and f:ajax. Although I have managed to move it there, it still continues to expect global JS Functions. The generated html code snippet had 3 args so used it.

Comment: The abuse of bold formatting made the question very hard to read. Half of the question was in bold. This wasn't making any sense. Use bold formatting to emphasize only, not to highlight the "relevant" parts, nor to markup code. If you think there are irrelevant parts in the question, you should instead remove them entirely to make the question better focused.

Comment: Oops. I'm sorry about it @BalusC . I'm quite new to this forum. Please excuse!

Comment: It isn't specific to this "forum" (Stack Overflow actually isn't a forum, it's a Q&A site). It's just (n)etiquette in general. You also don't bold out half of your resumes/letters this way?

Comment: Yes. I was wrong!. Pls excuse the mistake!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I figured this out. I'm not sure if this is the right method. But it works.

1. Remove the following section as its not right to create a dummy link just for the sake of triggering a click event on it (in order to make JSF ajax work). It also forces to define global handler call backs as mentioned above which pollutes the global namespace, prevents the modularization of JS code, makes it imposs to move to AMD:

> ```
> <h:commandLink id="elemID" tabindex="-1" rendered="#{something.isEnabled ('showSomeLink')}">
>     <f:ajax render="#{someBean.getElemId('LinkID')}" onevent="renderAjax" />
>     <jsft:event type="ajax"> someBean.someMethod(); </jsft:event>
> </h:commandLink>
> ```

1. Now create a simple XHTML file called ajax.xhtml that serves as a template.
2. Create another file called needHelp.xhtml that uses the above file ajax.xhtml as the template

Both steps (1) and (2) have been shown in an image below:
http://i61.tinypic.com/2rgypsi.png

3. In the backing bean, do this:
   http://i62.tinypic.com/1037bci.png

This completes the setup. Our Ajax response is now in the JSON format and written to the response stream.

Now, in the required AMD require Module,

```
define('checkChannel', ['jQuery', 'ajaxHandlers'], function($, ajaxHandlers){
  (function checkChannel(){
    $.ajax({
       url : baseURL+"/needHelp.jsf",
       dataType : "json",
       type: "POST",
       success : ajaxHandlers.renderAjax
    });
  })();
})
```

The *success* handler is used to update whatever DOM element needed, based on the response flags. In this case, it would update the element with id="LinkID", as defined in the original code snippet.

Now, the *renderAjax* is well wrapped inside an AMD module and is no longer required to be defined globally. Now there is no need to use the  and  or have dummy links created via  to simulate a click and trigger AJAX in JSF. If the view state needs to be maintained, it can always be got and updated in a similar manner.

> Also, baseURL is the basehref of your app. For example, if the page
>   was www.example.com/tool/index.jsf, then the baseUrl would be 
>   www.example.com/tool/. So, the AJAX URL would be
>   www.example.com/tool/needHelp.jsf
>
> PS: pardon the external image links as stackoverflow did not let me
>   post pics / more links as i needed atleast 10 reputation to post. I
>   had to use external images as I had some trouble formatting the code.